# Display Attributes of a Box

Tags: python, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to get my program to put out an output similar to this:

Length: 3

Width: 4

Height: 5

Color: Red

However I am currently getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/chaos/OneDrive/Documents/Python/Box_Assignment.py", line 30, in 
print(b1.get_attributes)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_attributes'

Let me know what you think, my code is below.

```
class Box():


    def __init__(self,Length,Width,Height,Color):
        self.length=Length
        self.width=Width
        self.height=Height
        self.color=Color

    def __str__(self):
        return 'length:'+(self.length)+'width:'+(self.width)+'height:'+(self.height)+'color:'+str(self.color)

    def get_attributes(self):
        attributes = self.length,self.width,self.height,self.color
        return attributes
        


b1=(3,4,5,'Red')

b2=(5,6,7,'Blue')

print(b1.get_attributes)
```

Comment: Try `b1=Box(3,4,5,'Red')`

Comment: That just gives me:

Comment: <bound method Box.get_attributes of <__main__.Box object at 0x000001BBB9C04460>>

Comment: Try `print(b1.get_attributes())`

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

When creating the object, include the class name:

```
b1 = Box(3,4,5,'Red')
```

When calling the class method, include the parenthesis:

```
print(b1.get_attributes())
```